# WARNING:root:NaN or Inf found in input tensor after update GPU card

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor, tensorboard

I tried to regenerate the result on [CTR-GCN](https://github.com/Uason-Chen/CTR-GCN.git) . The given code works well at the initially. Then i changed my GPU Card to RTX 3090ti. After that, install all the Nvidia drivers. But now, when i run the model I get "WARNING:root:NaN or Inf found in input tensor" this warning and brings the accuracy very low.

If anyone comes across this situation please do help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue when I changed from a 3070 to a 2060 Super. Ultimately, the problem could not be resolved until I switched back to the 3070. Interestingly, I had another model trained with a 1080ti and this also did not work with the 2060 Super but worked with the 3070.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33969408)